# Mediafoundation Media Source (Byte Array)

Tags: c#, c++, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

I am writing an application for streaming a video from one source to a destination with

1. PC 1
   1.1 Capturing video by a camera;
   1.2 Encode it to H.264 byte arrays by transform;
   1.3 Also display the video at PC 1 via EVR

and then transfer the arrays to another PC

2. PC 2
   2.1 Receive the byte arrays;
   2.2 Decode the arrays as normal video streams (RGB or YUV);
   2.3 Display it to a EVR

I can successfully implement 1.1 to 1.3 via creating Media Source in 1.1, transform in 1.2 and Media Sink in 1.3.
However, there is little resources on internet which describe how can we create byte arrays as Media Source (as in step 2.1). All the resources I found are using either **video camera** or **files** (MP4 files, etc.) as Media Source.
I have tried to create a custom Media Source by myself but it always return E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND.
Is there any resources/samples which I can refer to? It has some samples from Sourceforge or Microsoft but all use video camera or files as source only.

I write the application via C# with Media Foundation wrapper at http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/. However, I can also refer to C++ sources which I can "translate" it to C#.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally speaking you _won't_ use a `Byte[]` to represent an entire media-source - what 
 makes you so focused on using `Byte[]`, exactly? (The reason people don't use `Byte[]` is because media files can be tens of gigabytes in size, but .NET (even x64) cannot have a byte-array larger than 2GB - not to mention how slow it is to marshal a huge buffer around...

Comment: My application "streams" a video rather than encode/decode a video file. Therefore, the  "packet" size for each frame (sample) is small and I have found that after encoding by H.264, it is just less than 20000 bytes for each packet, and in each second it just has 30 frames (i.e., 30 packets). .Net (and Media Foundation) should be easy to handle data in such size.

Comment: Ah, okay - I thought you meant you had a single `Byte[]` representing an entire 8-hour movie or something. Sorry.

Comment: It's ok. Would anybody knows how to do please help. Thanks.

Comment: I thinnk you should use Google with : streaming protocol